# Bookmarklet javascript working in Chrome but no Firefox or Safari

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, safari, bookmarklet

I want to use this bookmarklet for flickr, the code I have is this

```
javascript:prompt('Copy the BBcode below','<div class="img-link"><a href="'+location.href+'">'+document.evaluate('//h1[@class="photo-title"]',document,null,XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,null).stringValue+'</a>')
```

So in Chrome, when I am at a page at Flickr (e.g this http://www.flickr.com/photos/zapeipaa/4876022306/in/photostream/ ), I click the bookmarklet and get the prompt with the code

```
<div class="img-link"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zapeipaa/4876022306/in/photostream/">Peace Memorial Park</a>
```

However in both Firefox and Safari the photo-title (in this case "Peace Memorial Park") is left out completely.

Is there a way to work around and get it to work in Safari at least?

Comment: perhaps alert the result of the xpath? Any errors in the console?

Comment: This works fine for me in FF4. Any possibility that you just copied the URL to the bookmark incorrectly?